When finding phasor's angle using arctan, why doesnt the author consider the location of the complex numbers?
The following shows up in a textbook (Control Systems: Principles & Design, M Gopal, 3rd edition, example 7.1)
F(s) is just a function in a complex number, mapping to another complex number (for those familiar with control theory, it's an open-loop transfer function). $\sigma$ and $\omega$ are just the real & imaginary parts of the input to the function. Its defined as follows, taken from that example,
$$F(s = \sigma + j\omega) = \frac{K \left( \sigma + b + j\omega \right)}{\left( \sigma + a_1 \right)\left( \sigma + a_2 \right) - \omega^2 + j\omega \left( 2\sigma + a_1 + a_2 \right)}\\\\
$$
The author claims that the following is the angle of F(s) taken as a phasor,
$$\angle F(s = \sigma + j\omega) = \tan^{-1} \frac{\omega}{\sigma + b} - \tan^{-1} \frac{\omega \left( 2\sigma + a_1 + a_2 \right)}{\left( \sigma + a_1 \right) \left( \sigma + a_2 \right) - \omega^2}$$
I dont think this is correct unless both complex numbers (the numerator & denominator) are on the right side of the complex plane, because of how arctan works. Is that right? We would need a $\pi$ offset, per term, if not. In general, dont we need to be careful about coordinates of the a complex number when trying to use arctan to get an angle?
Is it normal that I spent about an hour trying to make sense of whats going on here? Is it handwaving?
Edit: All constants are real & positive, and the author assumes s can be any complex number.

Instead of placing the functions in pictures, please write them using MathJax, as images cannot be searched. Many guides are available, e.g., https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

I know latex, should I write it in latex? If you dont mind me asking, why are images a problem, I dont understand.

Here is why images are a problem.

Got it, wont do it again.
